# variable con contenido html jquery

Tags: jquery

por que esto no funciona?

tengo una variable con una estructura `html`  que al hacer click en un boton la imprimo en una etiqueta `p` para luego al boton que se encuentra en esa variable agregarle una funcion `click` pero al hacer esto no me funciona.

lo mismo pasa cuango lo hago con `ajax` que por ejemplo si hago lo mismo con **ajax** tengo que agregar denuevo el `script` en el **ajax** para que pueda funcionar la funtion, a que se debe esto?

**NOTA:** los estilos css si los toma la variable con el contenido `html` pero no el script

aqui les dejo un ejemplo de lo que trato de hacer

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var contenido=`
     <div>
       <button id="pinchar2"> pinchar</button>
     </div>
    `;

    $('#pinchar').click(function() {
        alert("pinchado")
        $('p').html(contenido);
    });

    //luego al tratar de agregar la misma funcion a la variable me falla
    $("#pinchar2").click(function(){
        alert("pinchado")
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <button id="pinchar">check</button>
</div>
   
<p></p>
```

Comment: Deberías leer [eventos delegados](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) para entender, bastaría con asignar los eventos a un elemento existente, puede ser document para este caso, es decir `$(document).on("click","#pinchar2",function(){ ....});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que cuando buscas el botón #pinchar2 para asignarle el evento click, aún no ha sido añadido al dom, ya que es añadido hasta que das click en el botón #pinchar.

Lo que tienes que hacer es asignar el evento click hasta después de haberlo insertado en el dom:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var contenido=`
     <div>
       <button id="pinchar2"> pinchar</button>
     </div>
    `;

    $('#pinchar').click(function() {
        alert("pinchado")
        var p = $('p');
        p.html(contenido);

        p.find("#pinchar2").click(function(){
            alert("pinchado")
        });

    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <button id="pinchar">check</button>
</div>
   
<p></p>
```

Tu código lo que hace es ejecutarse al momento de cargar la página (evento ready).

Lo primero que hace es buscar el elemento #pinchar y le asigna una función a ejecutarse cuando se le dé click.

Luego, busca el elemento #pinchar2 para asignarle una función a ejecutarse cuando se le dé click, pero no lo encuentra porque aún no existe ese botón, ya que es creado hasta que das click en el botón #pinchar. Al no encontrar el botón #pinchar2, no le puede asignar el evento click.

Comment: no me quedo claro. como que aun no se ha agregado al dom? osea cuando haces lo siguente  `$('#pinchar').click(function() {
        alert("pinchado")
        var p = $('p');
        p.html(contenido);` esto se imprime inmediatamente  en el dom podrias aclararme eso

Comment: aun que tu codigo si funciona quiero tener algunos conceptos claros

Comment: Actualicé mi respuesta tratando de ser lo más claro posible.

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda ya entendi ,ahora bien por que si lo encuentra cuando agregas `find` si todavia no esta en el dom? osea por que que tiene de especial `find`?

Comment: El método find es solo para restringir la búsqueda del elemento #pinchar2 dentro del elemento p. Pero puedes usar $("#pinchar2").